# Const and non-const function as template parameter argument

Tags: c++, function, templates

I've been looking to deepen my understanding of templates and function pointers by creating a [very simple event/callback system](https://github.com/vlucki/EventSystem/blob/master/EventSystem/src/Event.h). I got to a point where I'd like to execute a given function regardless of it's constness in a more... "*template-y/generic*" way.

Currently there are two wrappers, one for non-`const` and one for `const` functions, which works well enough but just seems wrong since they are basically identical.

So here's a section of what I currently have:

**Non-Const function wrapper**

```
template<typename CallerType, typename ReturnType, typename ...Args>
    class RegularMemberFunctionWrapper : public MemberFunctionWrapper<CallerType, ReturnType, Args...>
    {
    private:
        ReturnType(CallerType::* funcPtr)(Args...);
    }
```

**Const function wrapper**

```
template<typename CallerType, typename ReturnType, typename ...Args>
    class ConstMemberFunctionWrapper : public MemberFunctionWrapper<CallerType, ReturnType, Args...>
    {
    private:
        ReturnType(CallerType::*funcPtr) (Args...) const;
    }
```

Ideally, I'd like to have only the parent "MemberFunctionWrapper", where I'd define via a template parameter whether the function is `const` or not.

```
template<typename CallerType, typename FunctionSignature, typename ...Args>
    MemberFunctionWrapper
    {
    private:
        FunctionSignature *funcPtr;
    }
```

Is something like this even possible with templates?

I saw some examples online where one template argument would define a type used by another (eg. `template<typename T, T T2>`) so maybe there's something to it? Perhaps what I want is not a **class** template, but **function** templates called by the derived classes (hence achieving the objective of eliminating code duplication)?

Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it it what you want, but you might have:

```
template<typename Sig>
class Wrapper
{
private:
    Sig funcPtr;
};
```

and so, possible usages such as:

```
Wrapper<void (C::*) (int) const> w1;
Wrapper<void (C::*) (int)> w2;
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/zeOmLV)

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to get your example working - at least not in the way I need it. The code just won't compile when I try to pass a function to the class' constructor, like: `Wrapper<void(Test::*)()> test(&Test::TestFunction);` where "TestFunction" is static and returns nothing.

Comment: I am only left with an error C2664 stating that "**cannot convert argument 1 from 'void (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'Sig *'**". The same for non-static functions.

Comment: "is static" - A pointer to static member function has the same type as a non-member function, like `void(*)()`, instead of the type of a non-static member function like `void(Test::*)()`, since a static member does not have or need the "this" parameter.

Comment: It did compile now, but it's not exactly _working_. I am unable to simply call `funcPtr()` in order to execute the function, either within `Wrapper` or  outside it. Which makes sense I guess, since executing member functions would require the object caller, right?

Comment: Perhaps it was not clear what I want this whole wrapper thing for.

I need to be able to store a function, member or not, `const` or not, and _call it later_, with a **generic return type** and **variable number of generic arguments**. Which I got working by using three classes: one for global functions, one for regular member functions and one for `const` member functions. 

What I was wondering (which led to this post) is if I could somehow unify the const and non-const member function wrappers, since [both are identical except the const keyword](https://www.diffchecker.com/Xi3HOGXi).

Comment: What is wrong with `std::function` (or `std::invoke`)?